# How to remove "Create: option in many 2 one field for user

Tags: odoo

How to remove "Create: option in search view opened after clicking Search view in `odoo 9`?
I want to hide create and hide option for many 2 one field for the user not for the manager?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove create option than you can do this via adding options `no_create`. For not allowing editing, you can do that via `no_edit` option. For the particular user group you want to add options than you can do this via different **access_rule** and **access_group**